# Is this possible to add Sort By Toolbar in Layer Navigation?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layered-navigation

I want to create new filter like Sort By in Sidebar Layer Navigation which currently display on the product listing page above the products grid.
[image]

**Want to add like below image:**
[image]

Is it possible in Magento 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check below link it will helps to you

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Magento-2-How-to-place-the-sort-option-in-the-left-layered/td-p/37785

Comment: Yes, It,s working. But there are lots of extra code in the files. Well, you saved my day. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome, If its worked please accept this answer, so another will use same :)